# Display multiple images which are sql Group_Concat

Tags: php, sql, ajax

First the dates are grouped like..

```
$a  = "SELECT  dates AS p FROM imgdb  WHERE id=1 GROUP by dates";
```

Then the images are GROUP_CONCAT by the date..

```
foreach ($a as $value) {

$res = SELECT  group_concat(images) AS img FROM imgdb  WHERE dates=$value";
}
```

Then I want to show this images on Ajax Success Function..

```
success: function(r) {
var res = JSON.parse(r)
$.each(res, function(index) {
$('.img').html(
$('.img').html()+'<img src"folder/'+res[index].img+'"/>'
}
```

How can this be done Pls Give suggesstion thanks..

Comment: Shouldn't you at least use a seperator in `GROUP_CONCAT`? Why use `GROUP_CONCAT` anyway? This'll return a string with all your image names glued together. I think you might be better off returning your images in an array rather than a string.

Comment: @kerbholz but then the images are displayed but if 3 images are uploaded then they are displayed seperately..that not how i want to show them.. One date 3 images like this thanks..